# How to make the wrapping div element with relative position match child elements height?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple problem where I have 2 divs, 1 is relative positioned. The child element is absolute positioned. This child has varying height.

The code so far:

HTML

```
<div id="wrap"><div id="inner"></div></div>
```

CSS

```
#wrap {
    width: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 20px;
}

#inner {
    width:30%;
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 200px;
}
```

The problem I have is that the #wrap element doesn't adjust its height to match the child element and therefor the child element hangs outside the edge of the parent. Can this be done with relative and absolute positioned elements?

I know this can be achieved with floating elements and following them with css => cleared: both, but I'd like to know if its possible with this method.

I've created a **[jsfiddle of this problem over here](http://jsfiddle.net/gR2wL/)** if anybody would like to help me out!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible. When you use absolute positioning it removes the element from the document flow... so even thought #inner is a child of #wrap, it is no longer treated as such. I would stick to using floats.

Comment: thats what I thought also. cheers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Absolute positionned elements are outside the flow so parents can't adjust their height.

But you can simply use:

```
#wrap {
    width: 100%; /* useless */
    background: #ccc;
    overflow:hidden; /* establish a new formatting context */
    min-height: 20px;
}

#inner {
    width:30%;
    background: #000;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, that solves the element not hanging over the edge of the parent but I'm aiming for the parent to stretch. Cheers anyways.

Comment: the parent will stretch, test it!

Comment: It would if you added `height: 200px` to `#inner`, as it has in the question.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood (I'm french ^^') you're right about using JavaScript (or table layout =p)

Answer (score 9):

No, you can't make a parent with `position: relative` adjust its `height` to fit a child element with `position: absolute`.

This is because:

> In the absolute positioning model, a
>   box is explicitly offset with respect
>   to its containing block. **It is removed
>   from the normal flow entirely** (it has
>   no impact on later siblings). An
>   absolutely positioned box establishes
>   a new containing block for normal flow
>   children and absolutely (but not
>   fixed) positioned descendants.
>   **However, the contents of an absolutely
>   positioned element do not flow around
>   any other boxes.**

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#absolute-positioning

If you wanted to stick with your `position` based code, you'd have to use JavaScript to set the `height` of the parent `div`.

Otherwise, stick to using `float`s if they work for your case. @MatTheCat's answer looks good to me.

Just for completeness, here's a demo of @MatTheCat's answer with `height: 200px` added, so you can see the parent `div` does adjust in `height`: http://jsfiddle.net/gR2wL/3/

Comment: Ahh bummer. I should read the documentation! Thanks for that.