# Absolute positioning div over top of floated div

Tags: jquery, css

I have two divs inside a parent div which is relative. One of the child divs is a float and the other is absolute because I need them to overlap. I have jQuery sliding the absolute div in from the right when the float div slides off to the left and disappears, however the parent div does not wrap around the absolute whereas it does with the float div, is there anyway I can make the parent div surround both elements?

```
    #part-one {  
       float:left;

    }

    #part-two {
       clear:both;    
       position:absolute;
       top:0;
    }

<div class="slider">
    <div id="part-one"></div>
    <div id="part-two"></div>
</div>

$('.next').click(function(){
   $("#part-one").hide('slide', { direction: "left" }, 1000);
   $("#part-two").hide('slide', { direction: "right" }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: can you show us the live demo of your code ?

Comment: CAn you show your HTML too? You might need to refactor this.

Comment: is not easy to understand what you mean... if you also have a small concept design will be better

Comment: So far [this demo](http://jsbin.com/ujasif/3/edit) is all I can imagine and works really fine... You did not posted any CSS related to your `.slider` and that's the important one!

Answer (score 0):

"the parent div does not wrap around the absolute whereas it does with the float div"

I guess this link [How to make the wrapping div element with relative position match child elements height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319500/how-to-make-the-wrapping-div-element-with-relative-position-match-child-elements) is similar to what you are talking about.